# When to call GPS reset

Tags: android, gps

I am building GPS app and I want to reset GPS to make faster fix. I am using this code to do it:

```
locationmanager.sendExtraCommand("gps", "force_xtra_injection", bundle);
locationmanager.sendExtraCommand("gps", "force_time_injection", bundle);
```

the question is when should I call it? Do I need GPS turned on and Internet connection to call this command? Or internet connection is enough? Or I can call it anywhere and the command will run ASAP?

Thanks in forward

Comment: those dont look like that many permutations. Its already been 2 days. Why dont u try it  for each case on a real device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need that.
Your device automatically uses assisted GPS if a network connection is available, when GPS is enabled. If GSM network is not enabled or roaming is disabled, it need some seconds more to download the "aid data" from satellite.
So forget that all.

What makes sense in speed up, is to use an inacurate Network location (e.g for load of map data) as long as no GPS loctaion is available.

Comment: actually it helps a bit. I have tested it on two same devices with same app (one with reset and one without). Device with reset got fix a lot faster so I think that it helped

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct way to do that:

sendExtraCommand looks like this

`LocationManager.sendExtraCommand (String provider, String command, Bundle extras)`

Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#sendExtraCommand%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29)

for `provider` use -> `LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER`

for `command` use -> `"delete_aiding_data"`

for `extras` use -> `null` to delete ALL data. The provider may optionally fill the extras Bundle with results from the command.

Returns
`true` if the command succeeds.

how it will actually look:

`locationManager.sendExtraCommand (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, "delete_aiding_data", null)`

You can decide to delete all GPS data or part of it. Check the example code with many useful logics -> [HERE](https://gitorious.org/android-eeepc/base/source/fd9f42a6967370490cd2c66e628ccbf2eacc4a4b:location/java/com/android/internal/location/GpsLocationProvider.java)

P.S. needs permission  `android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS`

Comment: I understand all of these but question is when should I call this method? What conditions should be met (do I need internet conenction? GPS enabled?)?

Comment: I checked it and sendExtraCommand returns true everytime (no matter if internet connection is on, or if GPS is on). But I dont think that these commands are succesfull without internet connection because they are downloading aiding data via internet

Comment: Data is defiantly downloaded from network. Haven't testet but I believe aiding data doesn't need network or Gps on, because ita stored data in android system that can be accessed any time.

Comment: yes but xtra and time injection force app to download data from synchronizing server so I think that they need network connection

Comment: Time is automatically synced to devices time on first fix. No need to download. What's the problem that user connects to network for this tasks?

Comment: I did a bit of additional testing so delete_aiding_data and force_time_injection returns true no matter if internet or GPS is on ... but force_xtra_injection returns false always ... is it possible that my samsung xcover 2 doesnt support xtra data?

Comment: @horin I have no idea why it always returns false, but that happens to me too with an unbranded device I am developing...but I realize that maybe, you did solve it, or lost interest, after 9 years XD